# Hide pdf to non registered users

Tags: php, pdf, authentication

I've hit a dead end with this code I'm working on.  I have a website where users can register and will be able to view certain pdfs when they are logged in.  My question is though, how do I hide this file to make sure that only those currently logged in can subscribe.  I keep track of my users with a MySQL database and have been using PHP for all the server side coding.  Ideally, the solution won't involve the user having to sign in again or anything like that.  I'm not necessarily looking for code (though its always appreciated :D), but any bump in the right direction would be great.

Thanks for any help you guys can offer.

Comment: How are you managing sessions? I imagine an answer would require that context.

Comment: Why do users need to login? Do they need to pay for the PDFs? If not, then it's just a punishment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['login']))
{
    header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    readfile('secret/books.pdf');
    exit();
}
else
{
    include('login.php');
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  This is just what I need.  And also a thanks to Philipp for the extra help.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to secure the URL to the user is to require a login, which is something you don't want to do. (Obviously as long as the session is open via a cookie or whatever you are using, the person could access it.)

But keep in mind that once a person as the link to the PDF, they can download it and give it to somebody else. So in my opinion, you should simply focus on making it impossible for the average person to guess the URL.

In other words, simply putting the PDF on a URL that is not guessable is sufficient security given that a person can easily duplicate the PDF.

That said, if you want to lock it down a bit, you could give each user his own unique URL for the PDF. Thus if somebody does copy the URL around, you know who did it. Also, you could have URLs expire after a certain time.

That URL could be stored in the database as a url -> pdf lookup. No authentication would be required to access it.

Comment: While it may be true that someone could share the PDF after gaining access to it, the same is true for just about anything you give private access to. I think it would be better to actually protect it, as @ayush and @Philipp K. Jaquet suggest.

Comment: @mfonda, to me it depends on the application. If requiring authentication is a burden to the users and the documents are not private in nature, then I would not worry about the pseudo-secure authentication. Instead, I would stick with a unique URL per user which could easily be monitored for suspicious activity. But if the documents were private/personal or the users tended to be "regular" visitors, then I would require authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Two thoughts on that:
1) store your PDF outside of your public readable WWW folder and include it to an authenticated user like ayush proposed
2) protect the file with a username and password using htaccess and access it with [curl](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php). cURL can provide the correct credentials without making the user re-authenticate.